# Unable to Upload Large File in ASP.Net Web Application (DotNetNuke), Web.Config is set for size and execution

Tags: file, iis, azure, upload, virtual-machine

I am a MS Azure VM user and am trying to get help with an issue where even thought in my Web.Config I have set the correct file size/request (set to 128MB) and execution time (9000), when I upload a file (just 32MB) via the asp.net file upload control in it fails with a 403 error (file not found). I have tried everything and am stumped. I am MCSD and MCSE so I know my way around so I am wondering if it is a Azure VM issue/Configuration item I am missing. Any assistance finding a solution would be great.  This is a critical issue that is preventing a software sale from going through and I really need to find a fix before they decide to move away from our solution.  We are a small startup so paying MS $$$ for support is something we are trying to avoid if at all possible...  Thank you in advance for your assistance...

Comment: You should quote the relevant parts of web.config and also 403 is not "file not found".

Answer (score 0):

I suspect you are running into an issue with the size of the ASPNETTEMP folder.  See http://blogs.msdn.com/b/kwill/archive/2011/07/18/how-to-increase-the-size-of-the-windows-azure-web-role-asp-net-temporary-folder.aspx for a complete solution showing how to configure an Azure webrole to upload large files via the fileupload control.

Also, in terms of paying for support, it is only $29 per month.  If you spend even 30 minutes trying unsuccessfully to troubleshoot something yourself, then the price of support will pay for itself.  Just something to think about...